# In VBA, how to check if a string contains any of many strings found in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, string, excel-formula

I'm struggling a bit to figure this one out, so I thought I'd ask here.

I have a cell with a LOT of words in it. I also have another cell with a compound word in it.
Say, as an example, that the compound word is PineappleTree, and my cell with the words has "Pineapple" in it, along with maybe 1000 other words.
The goal here is to be able to get a formula that should return TRUE or 1 or some value that indicates that part of the compound word was found or not in the other cell.
I could maybe cycle through each word with Instr but it wouldn't be very efficient I don't think, so I wanted to see if there was a better way to do this first.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a simpler solution... I would use `split` to create an array of the words from the "cell with words", loop though that and search with `instr`, breaking the loop when one found, as a small optimization.